# how to convert 'dask_cudf' column to datetime?

Tags: python, dask, rapids, cudf

How can we convert a **dask_cudf** column of string or nanoseconds to a datetime object? `to_datetime` is available in pandas and cudf. See sample data below

```
import pandas
import cudf

# with pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame( {'city' : ['Dallas','Bogota','Chicago','Juarez'], 
                      'timestamp' : [1664828099973725440,1664828099972763136,1664828094775313920,1664828081313273856]})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# with cdf
cdf = cudf.DataFrame( {'city' : ['Dallas','Bogota','Chicago','Juarez'], 
                      'timestamp' : [1664828099973725440,1664828099972763136,1664828094775313920,1664828081313273856]})
cdf['datetime'] = cudf.to_datetime(cdf['timestamp'])

print(df)
print(cdf)
```

in either case, the result is the same:

```
      city            timestamp                      datetime
0   Dallas  1664828099973725440 2022-10-03 20:14:59.973725440
1   Bogota  1664828099972763136 2022-10-03 20:14:59.972763136
2  Chicago  1664828094775313920 2022-10-03 20:14:54.775313920
3   Juarez  1664828081313273856 2022-10-03 20:14:41.313273856
```

[This recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889803/dask-cudf-dataframe-convert-column-of-datetime-string-to-column-of-datetime-obje) suggests using dask:

```
import dask_cudf
from dask import dataframe as dd

ddf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(cdf, npartitions=2)

dd.to_datetime(ddf['timestamp']).head()
```

produces an error. I am creating a dask_cudf from a large number of csv files in one directory.

Comment: This will be resolved by https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/9881 . For now, you can use the cuDF `to_datetime` within a `dask.dataframe.map_partitions` call.